# How to download assets/files(.JSON) and store them inside my app not directly on the user's phone in React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

am using React Native Expo and I was browsing the web to find a way to download assets, and files to my react native project and came across with this post [How to Download image in react native](https://aboutreact.com/download-image-in-react-native/)

When the user clicks the download button I want assets/files to be downloaded and stored  inside the app not directly on the user's phone. I mean I don't want the users to view the downloaded files or delete them manually.

**I just want the downloaded assets/files to be accessible by the React Native app.** Am doing this to make the app work offline.

Once the users downloaded the assets/files, the app can use the downloaded assets/files. How can I accomplish that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using expo managed workflow, then `rn-fetch-blob` will not work for you.
In that case, [Expo File System](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/) is probably your way to go.

Comment: Oh okay, can I save those files inside my app? I don't want the user edit or delete the file. I just want to make the files only accessible by the app.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, install `expo-file-system`. See [this](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/)

Next, for saving files and not letting users delete them manually, store them inside the `cache-directory` like this

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

const downloadAssets = async () => {
  let name = "Samplefile.jpg";
  const result = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
    url_Of_the_File_You_Want_to_Download,
    FileSystem.cacheDirectory + name
  );

  const response = await result.downloadAsync();
  if (response.status === 200) {
    // File successfully saved
  } else {
    // Some error
  }
};
```

To access this file in your app simple execute this function

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

const getFiles = async () => {
  const CacheDir = await FileSystem.readDirectoryAsync(
    FileSystem.cacheDirectory
  );
  console.log(CacheDir); //Files are stored here
};
```

Comment: Thanks brother! I will implement it and will let you know.

Comment: BTW is there a size limit for like AsyncStorage? (Android supports 5MB Max)